# How to use Cassandra in Django framework

Tags: django, cassandra, backend

Is there any robust way of implementing Cassandra back end to a web application developed using Django web framework?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

http://github.com/twissandra/twissandra is a django app with a Cassandra backend.  It uses https://github.com/datastax/python-driver to talk to Cassandra.

Comment: Do you know any good resources on implementing these technologies like tutorials, ebooks. Thanks in advance

Comment: ericflo no longer works on twissandra so we asked github to move it. Updated w/ new url, thanks.

Answer (score 27):

There is new Cassandra engine (based on cqlengine) for Django - https://github.com/r4fek/django-cassandra-engine

Comment: This project works very well. The naming is unfortunate, since it's very close to the (long abandoned) `django_cassandra_backend`..

Answer (score 9):

There now is a prototype Cassandra backend for Django available here: http://github.com/vaterlaus/django_cassandra_backend

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tried it out for myself, but this looks like something: http://github.com/dziegler/alexandra