# Cassandra and Django

Tags: python, django, cassandra

I'd like to use Cassandra from within django, and after some research I've noticed that there are some libraries that enable you to access cassandra from a higher level than [pycassa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pycassa) does: For django there's [alexandra](https://github.com/dziegler/alexandra) & [django-cassandra-backed](https://github.com/vaterlaus/django_cassandra_backend), for plain python you'll find [tragedy](https://github.com/enki/tragedy/) & [lazyboy](https://github.com/digg/lazyboy)...

I know there's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369793/how-to-use-cassandra-in-django-framework), but I'm specifially looking if anybody can provide any real world experiences about using on of the above (or maybe another) libraries... As all of them are supposed to do something similar and not all look totally up to date this would be very helpful!

Comment: This looks like a call for a long discussion rather than an answerable question.

Comment: Well maybe, but as there is not much information out there on this topic, I was hoping that the number of answers will still be small...

Comment: The only python clients that I'm aware of being actively maintained are pycassa (I'm the maintainer), telephus (Twisted), and the python CQL driver. The others you listed are pretty much dead, with the partial exception of django-cassandra-backend, which is still alive, but behind and not very active.

Comment: @tyler: you should have put it as an answer, because that was at least a statement of some sort i was expecting...

Comment: Use the right tool for the job. I suspect that you chose Cassandra because it scales storage. Does Django scale out horizontally like Cassandra? If it doesn't, it might not be the best choice if you're looking to distribute processing among multiple nodes. I'd use the typesafe stack for this.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/twissandra/twissandra is using Apache Cassandra and Django.
It's also a good entry point if you are curios about the Cassandra data model

Comment: I'm aware of Twissandra... Twissandra is using pycassa, but my question was if there are any higher level libraries, maybe especially for django... Otherwise using pycassa is the choices for sure...